# How to embed URL to a Footer Button in MC email template. Which Amscript function best server the purpose

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In the email template there is a Footer Button called **CHECK IT OUT** when clicked it must direct to URL defined by a field called “**FooterURL**” in the DE. I tried using **AttributeValue** Ampscript function but when rendering it is not directing to the URL defined by the**FooterURL** is defined. Which is best Ampscript function to use for this scenario?

```
<a href="%%=V(AttributeValue("FooterURL"))=%%" class="CTAbutton__text" style="color: #25861E; font-family: 'Fresh Sans', arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;">**CHECK IT OUT** &nbsp;›
```

Comment: <a href="**%%=V(AttributeValue("FooterURL"))=%%**" class="CTAbutton__text" style="color: #25861E; font-family: 'Fresh Sans', arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;">                                                    CHECK IT OUT &nbsp;›

Answer (score 1):

The AMPscript V function outputs the value of a variable. You will need to use:

`%%=RedirectTo(FooterURL)=%%`

Obviously, this requires a FooterURL to be in your Sendable DE, otherwise the email will error.

Incidentally, I did try using `%%=RedirectTo(AttributeValue(FooterURL))=%%` and `%%=AttributeValue("FooterURL")=%%` but for some reason, the link breaks when using an **inline** AttributeValue function.

Comment: when email is sent and click on "Check it Out" it  takes to weird URL " ** http://click.email.buybuy.at/?qs=1a94692844481a4eccf7e2ed58ce51e1c9d8c5b9bb6868a9b41a1e8ec4d51bffc295c655788884e4a13da33e766bd19c9637da13b2bc13a1** " not to the defined " https://ebay.com"  value in the Footer URL . Any thoughts

Comment: That would be the Marketing Cloud click tracking URL which should resolve to the target URL defined in your DE. Is there anything unusual about the URL? Does it contain an anchor? Are you able to provide a sample URL?

Comment: URL  is  https://www.ebay.com/(**https://www.ebay.com**) . Works on Email  Preview:  Opens the URL . But when Email is sent and opened in the inbox directls to URL directing to : **https://cl.exct.net/%%=AttributeValue(**  and comes with error msg Bad Request - Invalid URL. HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Comment: Current Code looks like this: `code`  <a href = **"%%=AttributeValue("FooterURL")=%%"** class="CTAbutton__text" style="color: #25861E; font-family: 'Fresh Sans', arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    Check it out &nbsp;›

Comment: Hi @GirishKrishnamurthy, you are correct. I've just validated this and I'm getting the same behaviour. I have updated my answer to reflect the correct implementation.

Comment: Code is  - **bold** <a href="%%=RedirectTo(Furl)=%%" class="CTAbutton__text" style="color: #25861E; font-family: 'Fresh Sans', arial; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle;"> Check it out &nbsp;›

Comment: @GirishKrishnamurthy that code should work, providing that the value of `Furl` in your sendable DE is a valid URL (e.g. starts with https:// or http://)

Comment: Thank you for your feed @Eliot Harper . The code needs to be ` "@Furl " <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Furl)=%% `